# Creating dynamic listeners with Spring Integration

Tags: spring, dynamic, jms, listener, integration

Is it possible to create dynamic jms listeners using Spring Integration as I will get a list of queues from a text file?  I know this question was asked 2 years ago in 2015 and answered wherenit was mentioned using configurer to register end points which I can do but wondering if there is a solution since that question waa asked for using Spring Integration as it's been 2 years.

Comment: Take a look at this - https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/advanced/dynamic-tcp-client

Comment: Can you provide the link to that old question, and clarify how your question is different.

Comment: Here is the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34063230/adding-dynamic-number-of-listenersspring-jms