# Pass multiple queue names to Spring JMSListener

Tags: spring-boot, spring-jms

How can i pass multiple queue name to my `JmsListener`.

```java
@JmsListener(destination = "#{'${solace.jms.queueNames}'.split(',')}"
```

In my property file:

```
solace.jms.queueNames =q1,q2,q3
```

But when I start the Spring Boot app I get the below error:

```
.s.j.l.DefaultMessageListenerContainer  : Setup of JMS message listener invoker failed for destination '[Ljava.lang.String;@1b30a54e' - trying to recover. Cause: Error creating consumer - internal error (Queue name "[Ljava.lang.String;@1b30a54e" contains illegal character [;])
```

How to resolve it?

Comment: If you want to listen on three queues, you will have to have three JMSListeners.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adding Dynamic Number of Listeners(Spring JMS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34063230/adding-dynamic-number-of-listenersspring-jms)

Answer (score 1):

You can define multiple `@JMSListener`

```java
@JmsListener(destination = "${solace.jms.queueNames[0]}")
@JmsListener(destination = "${solace.jms.queueNames[1]}")
@JmsListener(destination = "${solace.jms.queueNames[2]}")
```